# NFS: Synchronized processing of files in cluster env

Tags: java, websphere, nfs

There is a process which dumps 10k files in a shared NFS drive. I need to read and process the data from files. I have written java code which works great in a single node env. But when the code is deployed in WAS cluster with 4 nodes, the nodes are picking and processing the same files.

How can I avoid this? Is there some sort of file lock feature that I can use to fix this issue? Any help is highly appreciated.

More info:
I am using org.apache.commons.io.monitor library to poll the NFS directory every 10secs. Then, we read and process the files and then move the file to a post process folder. As mentioned, this works great in a single node env. When deployed in cluster, the nodes are polling the same file and processing them which is causing multiple calls with same data to a backend service.

I am looking for optimal solution.

PS:**The application which processes the files doesn't have access to any kind of database.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

"Is there some sort of file lock feature that I can use to fix this issue?" Not without doing some work on your end. You could create another file with the same name ending in .lock and have the application check to see if a lock file exists by creating the lock file and if it succeeds then it will process the file. If it fails it then knows one of the other cluster members already grabbed the lock file.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre! I am going to try this but not sure if this solution works with many threads from cluster nodes polling at the same time.